# How to change the permission of all text channels with discord.py and Python?

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I would like to make a command that allows to modify the permissions of all text channels with discord.py. For example, disable sending messages in all text channels.

I looked at the documentation for discord.py, and I saw that there is a PermissionOverwrite class (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=app#permissionoverwrite) allowing to do some things at the level of the permissions (notably with the function update).

```py
@client.command()
async def lock(ctx):
        ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
```

Comment: What do you mean "a all text channels"?

Comment: i mean all of text channels on server like using the bot to change  the permissions on all of texte channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`Guild.channels`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.channels) for a list of all the channels in the server and [`GuildChannel.set_permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.GuildChannel.set_permissions), as you already are using, for each channel.